# how to umount /dev/sda1 or to change for another partition?

Tags: mount, umount

Is about this title. I need to change my partition to NTFS and i can't because my HDD is occupied with Ubuntu.

Comment: Question does not make sense.  You can't unmount the partition the system is on, nor can you "change" it to ntfs.  What makes you want to do so?

Comment: i want to change to windows 7

Comment: Then install Windows... it will take care of formatting the drive.

Comment: i dont have CD only have pendrive bro

Comment: How to install Windows without a cd would be an entirely different question, and off topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can't if you want to continue using ubuntu. /dev/sda1 is your main partition and it cannot be changed to another file system without reformatting.

You need to use a live cd or another OS you have installed on your hard drive you reformat it, but you can't do it from inside ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and type 
`sudo umount /dev/sda1`

Comment: worked for me. my sda1 was my thumbdrive. unmounted and made into a boot disk for my new OS